# Spivak' proof that möbius band has not trivial tangent bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle, mobius-band

I'm reading Spivak's *Comprehensive introduction to differential geometry* and i came across the proof that the tangent bundle of the Möbius band (as he defines it at an early stage i presume) is not homeomorphic to $M\times\mathbb{R}^2$. Here is the complete proof. [image]

I got the first part of the proof. What i don't get is the conclusion where he says that it is clearly impossible to map etc... Here my attempt:
Let's suppose that there exist an homeomorphism such that takes fibre into fibre in a linear fashion $$\phi:T(M,i)\to M\times\mathbb{R}^2$$
For each $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ consider the subspace
$<f_{*}(v_{(\theta,0)})>$ where $v=(0,1)$. This subspace is mapped by $\phi$ onto a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then i have a collection of subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized by $\mathbb{S}^1$ and i wish to pick for each point in $\mathbb{S}^1$ a non zero vector on $\phi(<f_{*}(v_{(\theta,0)})>)$ in a continuous fashion. But how? Is it even possible? This is equivalent to lift to $\mathbb{S}^1$ a curve in
$\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: It's not a map to $\Bbb P^2$. It's a map to $\Bbb R$, namely the "normal line" to the central circle on the Möbius band. (It needn't be geometrically normal, but it is a complementary subspace to the tangent line of the circle.)

Comment: I have made some progress: instead of taking into consideration the dashed arrows, take the non-dashed ones. I can pick continuously these ones on the central circle: $\phi$ maps them onto $M\times\mathbb{R}^2$. Then on $M\times\mathbb{R}^2$, more precisely on the central circle, for each mapped vector take continuosly an orthogonal complement. Then go back with $\phi^{-1}$. You have now a vector on each point of the central circle with a non zero component on the "normal line" which is not possible.